# ffmpeg: mixing concat, apad and amerge in one call

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge multiple calls to ffmpeg into one single call.

I have 2 images, 1 video, and 1 sound to merge together.

Video: Image 1 (1sec), Image 2 (1sec -- fade onto video if possible), Video
Sound: Sound --- once video start, merge both sounds

I am able to perform those actions separately (generating a temporary video with images + video), and then merging both sounds, but I'd like to get something faster.

How can I merge those two filters onto only one ?

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 1 -i thumb.jpg -t 1 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -framerate 60 -t 1 -i theme.jpg -t 1 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -i video.mov -filter_complex '[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [3:0] [4:0] [4:1] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1' tmp.mov`

`ffmpeg -i tmp.mov -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]apad [b]; [b][1:a]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -ac 2 -shortest out.mov`

My guess would be something like this `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 1 -i thumb.jpg -framerate 60 -t 1 -i theme.jpg -i video.mov -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" -map 2:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -ac 2 -shortest out.mov`, but this one ends up with the following error: *Stream specifier ':0' in filtergraph description [0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 matches no streams.*

Any help would be appreciated ! (also if you know how to get the `fade` filter in my case, it would be great !)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this (no fade):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 1 -i thumb.jpg -t 1 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:d=1 -framerate 60 -t 1 -i theme.jpg -t 1 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:d=1 -i video.mov -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex '[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [3:0] [4:0] [4:1] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[video][audio],[audio]apad[audio],[audio][5:0]amix=duration=shortest[audio]' -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" out.mov
```

Comment: That's almost good, except I would like to keep the video length (+ the length of the two images) as the length of my video (right now I have a video + two images that are less longer than the sound), how can I modify your filter efficiently to ensure that ?

Comment: Remove `[audio]apad[audio],`

Comment: Paul, why both `-t 1` and `d=1` with aevalsrc?

Comment: I prefer `d=1`, `-t 1` was just left because I never used it.

Comment: Thanks Paul, if you have an idea for the fade feel free to answer this comment again!

Answer (score 0):

With a 1-second fade out of the 2nd image,

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 1 -i thumb.jpg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:d=1
       -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 1 -i theme.jpg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:d=1
       -i video.mov -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex  
     "[2]format=yuva420p,fade=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[2fo];[4][2fo]overlay[m];
      [0:v][1:a][2:v][3:a][m][4:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[video][audio];
      [audio][5:a]amix=duration=shortest[audio]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" out.mov
```